# How to print a string letter by letter recursively with a star between each?

Tags: java, recursion

I need to print a String letter by letter with a * between each letter.
I want to find a recursive solution and not an iterative one. The signature must be :

```java
public static String allStar(String a);
```

Comment: The principle of recursion: split the problem (charAt(0), substring(1)) handle the easy part, use the function again for the other part, don't forget the end-criteria (length == 1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beshambher's answer is a neat and easy way to do it. But if you want to do it recursively then :

```java
public static String allStar(String a) {
    if(a == null || a.isEmpty()) {        
        return "";
    }

    if(a.length() == 1) {
        return a;
    }        
    return  a.charAt(0) + "*" + allStar(a.substring(1));
}
```

Comment: Be a good example, make it safe for null and "" :-)

Comment: I think using `isBlank()` instead of `isEmpty()` produces the wrong results, according to the problem statement. `"  "` (two spaces) should become `" * "`, not `""`

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Yes. updated that with a comment.

Comment: What I meant was "never use `a.isBlank()` in this case", your comment seems to advice otherwise. :)
With `isBlank`, you'll ignore trailing whitespace, but not leading whitespace.

Comment: @CostiCiudatu The question states `letter by letter` and also `between each character` :-) so it is not clear if whitespace only strings need to be considered or not. I just intended to say if the OP prefers to ignore such string then use `isBlank` or use `isEmpty`

Comment: @GauthamM, even so, when using `isBlank`: `"  ABC  "` (two leading, two trailing spaces) becomes: `" * *A*B*C*"`, which is just weird. Using `.trim()` would probably render a more consistent result, but what about whitespace sequences in the middle of the string?

Comment: @CostiCiudatu Yeah got it. I think for such an input the output should be `" * *A*B*C* * "`. using `isBlank` would result in `" * "` not available in the end of the output string.

Comment: One final note: `if(a.length()==1) { return a; }` should suffice.

Answer (score 2):

Try this where first the string is split into array of strings of each character and then joined together with a `*` character in between them.

```
System.out.println(String.join("*",  a.split("")));
```

Comment: `String.join` is iterative, not recursive

Comment: Hmm my bad. In that case the other answer would be the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

```java
class AllStar {
    public static String allStar(String a){
        return allStar(0, a, "");
    }
    public static String allStar(int ch, String a, String res){
        if(a.length() == 0){
            return res;
        }
        if(ch == a.length() - 1){
            res += a.charAt(ch);
            return res;
        }
        else{
            res += a.charAt(ch) + "*";
            return allStar(ch + 1,a,res);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        System.out.println(allStar("aritro"));
    }
}
```

Explanation :

We pass in the starting character index in the `ch` argument. `a` takes in the String which is to be printed according to the specified format, i.e., with stars. `res` takes in the String where the result should be stored. The if-statement checks if the letter is the last one. If true, it just appends the letter without a star to the `res` String as it is specified that stars should be between letters. It also returns the formatted String stored in  `res`. If it is not the last letter, `ch` is incremented, the original String is passed as it is, and the formatted String is passed on as well. This continues till the last character is reached.

Comment: Your solution doesn't handle the empty string as input.

Comment: the signature of function allStar is given

Comment: @Turo this version does not depend on too many built in fucntions and this is a requirement for many educational scenarios. Just mentioned this edition so that if anyone wants to use a solution which does not use too many built-ins, this might come handy.

Comment: Then make it two functions, the public allStar and yours as private, see @AlexRudenko's answer

Answer (score 0):

Solution for recursive **print** a string

```
public static void allStar(String a) {
    if (a != null && !a.isEmpty()) {
        System.out.print(a.charAt(0));
        if (a.length() > 1) {
            System.out.print('*');
            allStar(a.substring(1));
        }
    }
}
```

Solution for recursive **build** a string

```
public static void allStar(String a, StringBuilder builder) {
    if (a != null && !a.isEmpty()) {
        builder.append(a.charAt(0));
        if (a.length() > 1) {
            builder.append('*');
            allStar(a.substring(1), builder);
        }
    }
}
```

For reducing heap pollution, this one is the *best* for recursive string **build**

```
public static void allStar(String a, int position, StringBuilder builder) {
    if (a != null && position < a.length()) {
        builder.append(a.charAt(position));
        if (++position < a.length()) builder.append('*');
        allStar(a, position, builder);
    }
}
```

Use this for print recursivly builded string

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    allStar("test", 0, builder);
    System.out.print(builder);
}
```

Solution with recursions not recommended, but possible for this task.

Comment: Or with Java 8 orlater you can use streams `a.chars().forEach(c -> System.out.print((char) c + "*"))`

Comment: that's Java 9 or later. And this solution adds a `*` after the last character, which is not ideal. What could work instead is `a.chars().mapToObj(Character::toChars).map(String::valueOf).collect(Collectors.joining("*"))`

Comment: Yes, you are right, the last asterisk does not need.  I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

try this code :

```
public class Main {

static String Answer = "" ;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Main.SetStarAfterEachLetter("hello!");

        System.out.println(Answer);

    }


public static void SetStarAfterEachLetter(String letter){

    Answer = Answer + letter.charAt(0);
    Answer = Answer + " * ";
    letter = letter.substring(1);

    if(!letter.isEmpty()) {
        SetStarAfterEachLetter(letter);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Example implementation using overloaded functions `addStar(String str)` and `addStar(int pos, String str)`:

```
public static String addStar(String str) {
    if (null == str || str.isEmpty()) {
        return str;
    }
    return addStar(0, str);
}

static String addStar(int pos, String str) {
    if (pos == str.length() - 1) {
        return Character.toString(str.charAt(pos));
    }
    return str.charAt(pos) + "*" + addStar(pos + 1, str);
}
```

Tests

```java
System.out.println(addStar(null));
System.out.println("'" + addStar("") + "'");
System.out.println(addStar("a"));
System.out.println(addStar("ab"));
System.out.println(addStar("abcd"));
```

Output

```
null
''
a
a*b
a*b*c*d
```

Answer (score 0):

this is more general answer :

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

public class Main {

```
static String Answer = "" ;


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        String word = scanner.nextLine();

        Main.SetStarAfterEachLetter(word);

        System.out.println(Answer);

    }


public static void SetStarAfterEachLetter(String letter){

    Answer = Answer + letter.charAt(0);
    Answer = Answer + " * ";
    letter = letter.substring(1);

    if(!letter.isEmpty()) {
        SetStarAfterEachLetter(letter);
    }
}
```